# Transfer data between MyBook NAS Drives

Tags: mybook

I have two My Book World NAS drives, a 1TB and a 2TB.

Is there a way of transferring data between the two drives directly, without having to us a computer as an intermediary?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have one of these devices, so I can't be specific. But I do know they run some variety of linux so you should be able to get a login to one of them and initiate direct copies between the two.

Have a look at this site and use your imagination ... http://martin.hinner.info/mybook/

Looks like you need to update firmware, enable root access and the probably enable NFS and cross mount the drives.

Comment: Adding a disclaimer here since the author did not: This requires modifying your drives which may void your warranty (warranties).